# Use huggingface's model using new data

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, huggingface

Is there a way to use huggingface's model but retrain it on my data? My data is specifically Vietnamese accented words. I don't know how to put my data into the model. model and I want the model to be able to answer Vietnamese questions based on the Vietnamese data I provide to it. I don't know what to do with the data problem:

1. Don't know whether to choose Json or csv data type
2. How should the data be structured so that the model can understand it?
3. The model I am choosing is Google's T5, specifically google/flan-t5-base
4. How should I configure it?
   Request I want:
5. The model answers questions based on the data provided
   Please suggest me, thank you

I tried to learn from YouTube, tried to read the documentation, but I still find it very difficult to understand what data structure is, and how to put it. There are a few examples on YouTube that I have tried but unfortunately they are running on colab pro I only have colab free so I can't run the whole thing, can you give a brief summary or an example of how the data should be structured? And there is an example I found and I feel like The most confusing part is the endcode, why does it output 0 and 1 at the same time?
The code containing the printed value ex = next(iter(train_ds))
print("Example data from the mapped dataset: \n", ex)
here is the link:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/snapthat/TF-T5-text-to-text/blob/master/snapthatT5/notebooks/TF-T5-Datasets%20Training.ipynb#scrollTo=OQ5CoTk-DXN6